# Populate Picker with Data using MVVM Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I am trying to get a picker to populate with data. There doesn't seem to be a straight answer anywhere on this. I have tried numerous things, one thing that does work is :

Xaml:

```
<Picker Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
           Title="Driver Name"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Drivers}"                
            SelectedItem="{Binding driverID}"
```

and in the View Model:

```
List<string> Drivers = new List<string> { "Steve","Dave" };
```

This works fine, but its just a dummy capability as in the future these names will be grabbed from a service of some kind.
So in an attempt to copy this I tried separating this list into a mock service and just returning the list to the view model and making it work that way.

But this still returns nothing to the front end even though I can see that the list is not blank when debugging.
Then I tried to create a class of Driver and return instances of the class that has the name in it and access it in the Xaml.
This did not work, I even tried a variation using IList, this did not work either.

I am not sure why this does not work as the list was just separated to essentially a different class. For instance this is what I am trying now:

Xaml:

```
 <Picker Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
           Title="Driver Name"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Drivers}"                
            SelectedItem="{Binding driverID}"
            />
```

View Model:

This is bound to the picker

```
public List<string> Drivers;
```

Then this method is called from the constructor:

```
 public async Task FindDriverNames()
    {
        Drivers = await GetDriverNames();           
    }
```

and in the Model:

```
 public async Task<List<string>> GetDriverNames()
        {
            await Sleep();

            List<string> _drivers = new List<string> { "Steve"};

            return _drivers;          

        }
```

This does not work, but when run through debug it shows that Drivers is populated.
I have wasted a lot of time trying to get this work, does anyone have insights?

Comment: Instead of List<string> use ObservableCollection<string>.

Comment: I will give this a try

Comment: and you should probably do Drivers.AddRange(...) instead of assignment...

Comment: @RomanAnanyev: and call `Clear` befor if you are updating :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an `ObservableCollection`, and possibly a `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation to notify the view for any changes.

```
public class YourViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public YourViewModel()
     { 
         Drivers = new ObservableCollection<string>();
     }

     private ObservableCollection<string> _drivers;
     public ObservableCollection<string> Drivers
     {
         get { return _drivers; }
         set
         {
            if (Equals(value, _drivers)) return;
            _drivers= value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Drivers));
         }
     }

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
}
```

By implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you will allow the view to be updated whenever the whole list changes. The observable collection will notify the UI if a item is added to the collection.

As noted by Roman, youo can also, in this specific case use the observable collection to update the `ui`.

```
public async Task FindDriverNames()
{
    Drivers.Clear();
    Drivers.AddRange(await GetDriverNames());           
}
```

For other `bound` properties you'll still need the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

See [ObservableCollection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So this is for the view model or the model?
Also how does this access the data in model?
Sorry for the questions but I am new to Xamarin

Comment: Sorry, my bad, this is the view model. The one you bind to the view through `BindingContext = new YourViewModel()`

Comment: Thanks!
Also how does this access the data that is in the model class?

Comment: I ask because later this will be going out and getting the names from a service

Comment: Or do I call the GetDriverNames method as before?

Comment: From the constructor

Comment: I wouldn't call it from the constructor because that's bad practice since it's an async call and can be hard to handle if an exception is thrown.

Comment: This worked! I will look at re-positioning the call to get the data though. Thanks!

Comment: OnAppering might be a good trigger. But beware, it will also trigger if anyone leaves and enteres the app.